# Preferable ways for reusing input components in react native?

Tags: react.js, react-native

**I am using react native 0.68.5**

When I call the `renderReusableTextInput` method in `Main.js` I am sending all the styles including the needed and unneeded styles. This can lead performance penalty.

So, is there a way that I can send the only needed styles to the `renderReusableTextInput` method.

I also want to know is the code reusing approach of mine correct or there are better ways.

I have the following code-logic structure:

(i) A Reusable component; It has only structure no style or state

(ii) A file that includes reusable methods

(iii) The Main component, which contains components, styles and states

**ReusableTextInput.js**

---

```
// import ...

const ReusableTextInput = forwardRef(({
  inputName,
  inputLabel,
  inputValue,
  secureTextEntry,
  textInputContainerWarperStyle,
  textInputContainerStyle,
  textInputLabelStyle,
  textInputStyle,
  textInputHelperStyle,
  textInputErrorStyle,
  helperText,
  inputError,
  onFocus,
  onChangeText,
  onBlur,
}, inputRef) => {

  return (
    <View style={[textInputContainerWarperStyle]}>
      <View style={[textInputContainerStyle]}>
    <Text style={[textInputLabelStyle]}>
      {inputLabel}
    </Text>
    <TextInput
      ref={(elm) => inputRef[inputName] = elm}
      style={[textInputStyle]}
      value={inputValue}
      secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
      onChangeText={onChangeText}
      onFocus={onFocus}
      onBlur={onBlur}
    />
      </View>
      {
        ((inputRef[inputName]) && (inputRef[inputName].isFocused()) && (!inputValue))
          ?
          <Text style={[textInputHelperStyle]}>
            {helperText}
          </Text>
          :
          null
      }
      {
        ((inputError) && (inputValue))
          ?
          <Text style={[textInputErrorStyle]}>
            {inputError}
          </Text>
          :
          null
      }
    </View>
  );
});

export default memo(ReusableTextInput);
```

**reusableMethods.js**

---

```
// import ...

const handleFocus = (state, setState, styles) => {
  // here styles contains all style key which I do not want
  // I only want the required styles

  const stateData = { ...state };

  stateData.styleNames.textInputContainer = {
    ...styles.textInputContainer,
    ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInputContainer`],
    ...styles.textInputContainerFocus,
  };
  stateData.styleNames.textInputLabel = {
    ...styles.textInputLabel,
    ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInputLabel`],
    ...styles.textInputLabelFocus,
  };
  stateData.styleNames.textInput = {
    ...styles.textInput,
    ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInput`],
    ...styles.textInputFocus,
  };

  // other logics...

  setState(stateData);
};

const handleChangeText = (state, setState, text) => {
  const stateData = { ...state };

  // individual validation
  const schemaData = Joi.object().keys(stateData.validationObj); // I used Joi for validation
  const inputData = { [stateData.name]: text };

  const options = { abortEarly: false, errors: { label: false } };

  const result = schemaData.validate(inputData, options);
  // -----

  stateData.error = (result.error) ? result.error.details[0].message : '';

  stateData.value = text;

  // other logics...

  setState(stateData);
};

const handleBlur = (state, setState, styles) => {
  // here styles contains all style key which I do not want
  // I only want the required styles

  const stateData = { ...state };

  if (stateData.value) {
    stateData.styleNames.textInputContainer = {
      ...styles.textInputContainer,
      ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInputContainer`],
      ...styles.textInputContainerFocus,
      ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInputContainerFocus`],
      ...styles.textInputContainerBlurText,
      ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInputContainerBlurText`],
    };
    stateData.styleNames.textInputLabel = {
      ...styles.textInputLabel,
      ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInputLabel`],
      ...styles.textInputLabelFocus,
      ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInputLabelFocus`],
      ...styles.textInputLabelBlurText,
      ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInputLabelBlurText`],
    };
    stateData.styleNames.textInput = {
      ...styles.textInput,
      ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInput`],
      ...styles.textInputFocus,
      ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInputFocus`],
      ...styles.textInputBlurText,
      ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInputBlurText`],
    };
  }
  else {
    stateData.styleNames.textInputContainer = { ...styles.textInputContainer, ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInputContainer`] };
    stateData.styleNames.textInputLabel = { ...styles.textInputLabel, ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInputLabel`] };
    stateData.styleNames.textInput = { ...styles.textInput, ...styles[`${stateData.name}ExtraTextInput`] };
  }

  // other logics...

  setState(stateData);
};


// other methods...


export const renderReusableTextInput = (
  state,
  setState,
  inputRef,
  styles, // contains all the styles from Main component
) => {

  return (
    <ReusableTextInput
      inputName={state.name}
      inputLabel={state.label}
      inputValue={state.value}
      inputRef={inputRef}
      secureTextEntry={state.secureTextEntry}
      textInputContainerWarperStyle={{...styles.textInputContainerWarper, ...styles[`${state.name}ExtraTextInputContainerWarper`]}}
      textInputContainerStyle={state.styleNames.textInputContainer}
      textInputLabelStyle={state.styleNames.textInputLabel}
      textInputStyle={state.styleNames.textInput}
      textInputHelperStyle={{...styles.textInputHelper, ...styles[`${state.name}ExtraTextInputHelper`]}}
      textInputErrorStyle={{...styles.textInputError, ...styles[`${state.name}ExtraTextInputError`]}}
      helperText={state.helperText}
      inputError={state.error}
      onFocus={() => handleFocus(state, setState, styles)}
      onChangeText={(text) => handleChangeText(state, setState, text)}
      onBlur={() => handleBlur(state, setState, styles)}
    />
  );
};
```

**Main.js**

---

```
// import Joi from 'joi';
// import { joiPasswordExtendCore } from 'joi-password';

// import { renderReusableTextInput } from ''; ...


const schema =
{
  email: Joi.string().strict()
    .case("lower")
    .min(5)
    .max(30)
    .email({ minDomainSegments: 2, tlds: { allow: ["com", "net", "org"] } })
    .required(),

  countryCode: // Joi.string()...,

  phoneNumber: // Joi.string()...,

  password: // Joi.string()...,
  // ...
};

const Main = () => {

  const { width: windowWidth, height: windowHeight, scale, fontScale } = useWindowDimensions();

  const minimumWidth = (windowWidth <= windowHeight) ? windowWidth : windowHeight;

  const styles = useMemo(() => currentStyles(minimumWidth), [minimumWidth]);

  const [email, setEmail] = useState({
    name: 'email', // unchangeable
    label: 'Email', // unchangeable
    value: '',
    error: '',
    validationObj: { email: schema.email },  // unchangeable
    trailingIcons: [require('../../file/image/clear_trailing_icon.png')], // unchangeable
    helperText: 'only .com, .net and .org allowed', // unchangeable
    styleNames: {
      textInputContainer: { ...styles.textInputContainer, ...styles.emailExtraTextInputContainer },
      textInputLabel: { ...styles.textInputLabel, ...styles.emailExtraTextInputLabel },
      textInput: { ...styles.textInput, ...styles.emailExtraTextInput },
    },
  });

  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState({
  });

  const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = useState({
  });

  const [password, setPassword] = useState({
  });

  // ...
 
  const references = useRef({});


  return (
    <View style={[styles.mainContainer]}>
      {
        useMemo(() => renderReusableTextInput(email, setEmail, references.current, styles), [email, minimumWidth])
      }
    </View>
  );
}

export default memo(Main);



const styles__575 = StyleSheet.create({
  // 320 to 575
  mainContainer: {
  },
  textInputContainerWarper: {
  },
  emailExtraTextInputContainerWarper: {
  },
  countryCodeExtraTextInputContainerWarper: {
  },
  phoneNumberExtraTextInputContainerWarper: {
  },
  passwordExtraTextInputContainerWarper: {
  },
  textInputContainer: {
  },
  emailExtraTextInputContainer: {
  },
  textInputContainerFocus: {
  },
  textInputContainerBlurText: {
  },
  textInputLabel: {
  },
  emailExtraTextInputLabel: {
  },
  textInputLabelFocus: {
  },
  textInputLabelBlurText: {
  },
  textInput: {
  },
  emailExtraTextInput: {
  },
  textInputFocus: {
  },
  textInputBlurText: {
  },
  textInputHelper: {
  },
  emailExtraTextInputHelper: {
  },
  textInputError: {
  },
  emailExtraTextInputError: {
  },

  // other styles...
});

const styles_576_767 = StyleSheet.create({
  // 576 to 767 
});

const styles_768_ = StyleSheet.create({
  // 768; goes to 1024;
});

const currentStyles = (width, stylesInitial = { ...styles__575 }, styles576 = { ...styles_576_767 }, styles768 = { ...styles_768_ }) => {
  let styles = {};

  if (width < 576) {
  }
  else if ((width >= 576) && (width < 768)) {
  }
  else if (width >= 768) {
  }

  return styles;
};
```

Comment: To help reviewers give you better answers, we need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*.  Please add sufficient context to your question to describe the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  Also, [edit] the **title** to simply [**summarise the task**](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: @TobySpeight, I will try.

Comment: This code seems incomplete.  For example, `currentStyles` has if statements for various `width` ranges, all of which are empty.  Please post complete code.

Comment: @AJNeufeld, for simplicity I wrote that way, nothing important inside those empty if blocks. If I wrote full code for every block, then it will be more complicated to understand. So, I intentionally wrote this post that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you want global styles, so that you can access it from anywhere and you can also be able to execute needed code.

Make sure you use `useMemo`, `useCallback` in right manner, for better performance.

Move all `Schema` and `Styles` and `Methods` of your screens inside the `reusableMethods.js` file (at most case). It will act like the **controller** of all `screens` of your app, **`also make a demo method which return a tiny component and this method execute another method, so that you can get styles for different dimentions(see below code)`**

Store only **changeable** and **needed** properties in `state` variables.

`Is code reusing approach of yours, correct?` I can't say about that. I will say that it depends on developer choice.

you can try like below:

**reusableMethods.js**

---

```
// import all schema, style variants, utility methods and other

let screenStyles = {};

const executeDimensionBasedMethods = (width, screenName) => {
  if (screenName === 'a_screen_name') screenStyles[screenName] = currentStyles(width, otherParameter);
  // else if()
  // ...
};

export const renderDimension = (width, screenName) => {
  executeDimensionBasedMethods(width, screenName);
  return (
    <Text style={{ width: 0, height: 0 }}></Text>
  );
};

// all method definitions and logics

export const renderReusableTextInput = (
  state,
  setState,
  inputRef,
  screenName
) => {
  return (
    <ReusableTextInput 
      inputName={state.name}
      inputLabel={state.label}
      inputValue={state.value}
      inputRef={inputRef}
      secureTextEntry={state.secureTextEntry}
      textInputContainerWarperStyle={{ ...screenStyles[screenName].textInputContainerWarper, ...screenStyles[screenName][`${state.name}ExtraTextInputContainerWarper`] }}
      textInputContainerStyle={state.styleNames.textInputContainer || { ...screenStyles[screenName].textInputContainer }
      textInputLabelStyle={state.styleNames.textInputLabel || { ...screenStyles[screenName].textInputLabel }
      textInputStyle={state.styleNames.textInput || { ...screenStyles[screenName].textInput }
      textInputHelperStyle={{ ...screenStyles[screenName].textInputHelper, ...screenStyles[screenName][`${state.name}ExtraTextInputHelper`] }}
      textInputErrorStyle={{ ...screenStyles[screenName].textInputError, ...screenStyles[screenName][`${state.name}ExtraTextInputError`] }}
      helperText={state.helperText}
      inputError={state.error}
      onFocus={() => handleFocus(state, setState, screenStyles[screenName])}
      onChangeText={(text) => handleChangeText(state, setState, text)}
      onBlur={() => handleBlur(state, setState, screenStyles[screenName])}
    />
  );
};
```

**Main.js**

---

````
const Main = () => {
  const { width: windowWidth, height: windowHeight} = useWindowDimensions();

  const minimumWidth = (windowWidth <= windowHeight) ? windowWidth : windowHeight;

  const [email, setEmail] = useState({
    name: 'email', // unchangeable
    label: 'Email', // unchangeable
    value: '',
    error: '',
    trailingIcons: [require('../../file/image/clear_trailing_icon.png')], // unchangeable
    helperText: 'only .com, .net and .org allowed', // unchangeable
    styleNames: {
      textInputContainer: undefined,
      textInputLabel: undefined,
      textInput: undefined,
    },
  });

  // other states 

  const references = useRef({});


  return (
    <>
      {
        useMemo(() => renderDimension(minimumWidth), [minimumWidth])
      }
      <View style={{ // inline style}}>
        {
          useMemo(() => renderReusableTextInput(email, setEmail, references.current, 'nameofscreen'), [email, minimumWidth])
        }
      </View>
  </>
}

export default memo(Main);
```
````